# Creating a Boxplot with Matplotlib for big data

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

**Hello, I need help. First I can create a basic boxplot shape like this,**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)
b = np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)
c = np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)
f = [a, b, c]
plt.boxplot(f)
```

**but how do I create a graph when my data is like this?  in this case there are six boxplots that should be generated.**

```
a = (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)), (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)), (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))
b = (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)), (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)), (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))
c = (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)), (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)), (np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))
```

***thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

The `boxplot` is taking `list` so you need to convert each element in the new abc from a tuple of arrays to a list.

Here is an example which will produce 3 boxplots for each of the above:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)
b = np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)
c = np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)

a1 = list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))), list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))), list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)))
b1 = list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))), list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))), list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)))
c1 = list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))), list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5))), list((np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)))


# f = [a,b,c]

plt.boxplot(a1)
plt.show()


plt.boxplot(b1)
plt.show()


plt.boxplot(c1)
plt.show()
```

The output is 3 of these:
[image]

Comment: thanks, but in this case there are six boxplots that should be generated. I should have explained this.

Comment: when you say 6,  do you mean `a`, `b`, `c`, `a1`, `b1`, `c1` all on to the same chart ?  if so, you can combine boxplots too. Here is an example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630857/how-to-combine-two-boxplots-with-the-same-axes-into-one-boxplot-in-python